# elementor import_templates coding not importing template

Tags: arrays, json, wordpress, templates, elementor

Could someone assist me in this code. as i am importing a JSON template file from the theme directory and setting the imported JSON file as the front page by passing the available template ID. I have a admin_menu button on the WordPress dashboard, and when it's clicked, it will trigger the function pasted below. Your help is greatly appreciated.

//code i have used

```
if (class_exists('Elementor\Plugin')) {
    $template_file_path = get_stylesheet_directory().'/assets/exampleTemplate.json';

    $template_content = file_get_contents($template_file_path);
    $template_data = json_decode($template_content, true);

    if (is_array($template_data)) {
        if ($template_data !== null) {
            $template_manager = \Elementor\Plugin::$instance->templates_manager;
            $imported_template = $template_manager->import_template($template_data);

            if (!is_wp_error($imported_template)) {
                $imported_template_id = $imported_template['template_id'];

                // Set the imported template as the front page
                update_option('page_on_front', $imported_template_id);
                update_option('show_on_front', 'page');

                wp_send_json_success('Template imported successfully and set as the front page.');
            } else {
                $error_message = $imported_template->get_error_message();
                wp_send_json_error('Error importing template: ' . $error_message);
            }
        } else {
            wp_send_json_error('Error decoding JSON file.');
        }
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error('JSON file not found.');
    }
} else {
    wp_send_json_error('Elementor is not active.');
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my problem is : code not working

Comment: The keywords you want to study next are: early if returns. The whole concept is based on writing code to check if something exists before proceeding: `if(!a) { return false; } else { return true; }` This pattern will cause error handling to naturally occur to you so you start writing code that is easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I'd begin by making sure I have the correct file path, JSON structure, and Elementor active. Also, consider using `get_template_directory()` for parent theme or `get_stylesheet_directory()` for child theme based on your setup.

This example adds more specific error checks, making it **easier to troubleshoot** if something goes wrong.

It makes sure the template file exists, checks for JSON errors, and validates that Elementor is active before proceeding.

```php
if (class_exists('Elementor\Plugin')) {
    $template_file_path = get_template_directory() . '/assets/exampleTemplate.json'; // For parent theme

    if (file_exists($template_file_path)) {
        $template_content = file_get_contents($template_file_path);
        $template_data = json_decode($template_content, true);

        if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE && is_array($template_data)) {
            $template_manager = \Elementor\Plugin::$instance->templates_manager;
            $imported_template = $template_manager->import_template($template_data);

            if (!is_wp_error($imported_template)) {
                $imported_template_id = $imported_template['template_id'];
                update_option('page_on_front', $imported_template_id);
                update_option('show_on_front', 'page');
                wp_send_json_success('Template imported successfully and set as the front page.');
            } else {
                wp_send_json_error('Error importing template: ' . $imported_template->get_error_message());
            }
        } else {
            wp_send_json_error('Invalid JSON file.');
        }
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error('Template file not found.');
    }
} else {
    wp_send_json_error('Elementor is not active.');
}
```

#### Example 2

Refactor code using ternary and null coalescing operators to reduce `if` statements.

**Less readable** but pretty cool, if your code won't be changing much.

Always consider the trade-off between readability and minimizing conditional statements.

```php
$classExists = class_exists('Elementor\Plugin');
$template_file_path = $classExists ? get_template_directory() . '/assets/exampleTemplate.json' : null;
$template_content = $template_file_path && file_exists($template_file_path) ? file_get_contents($template_file_path) : null;
$template_data = $template_content ? json_decode($template_content, true) : null;
$jsonValid = ($template_data && json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE && is_array($template_data));
$template_manager = $jsonValid ? \Elementor\Plugin::$instance->templates_manager : null;
$imported_template = $template_manager ? $template_manager->import_template($template_data) : null;

$response = !$classExists ? 'Elementor is not active.' :
            (!$template_file_path ? 'Template file not found.' :
            (!$jsonValid ? 'Invalid JSON file.' :
            (is_wp_error($imported_template) ? 'Error importing template: ' . $imported_template->get_error_message() : 
            (update_option('page_on_front', $imported_template['template_id']) && update_option('show_on_front', 'page')) && 
            wp_send_json_success('Template imported successfully and set as the front page.'))));

if (is_wp_error($response)) {
    wp_send_json_error($response);
} else {
    wp_send_json_success($response);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response I will consider this.